# Fantasy. Man wakes in a place where people live underground, is guest at wedding

Tags: story-identification

This was a thick book from the 1970s/1980s.

Man passes out in his home, wakes in a place where people live underground. He is asked to be guest at wedding.  Above the ground it's barren.

He visits a school where children learn by going off into space attached by some kind of hose.  At the end he is walking down road, surrounded by flowers viewing people getting older and almost returning to babies. He wakes.

I think he visited the cells of himself. What I mean by cells is the cells in his body. A world within himself. He is viewing the flowers and the people getting older as they walk down the path.

Comment: @user14111 I believe they are trying to ID a story, from how it reads, if so, could you please [edit] you question to make that a bit clearer. Could you also say when you read it, when it may have been published and any and all details you may remember?

Comment: After these years away, can you provide any more details? And by "the cells of himself", do you mean like the bodily structures? Prison cells? Monastic cells? And is he walking down the road, surrounded by flower, viewing people getting older, or are the flowers doing the viewing?